# How do i fix this error in bukkit/plugin programming: java:cannot find symbol constructor CommandExecute()

Tags: java, bukkit

I recently started creating a small plugin for my Minecraft bukkit/spigot server (Minecraft Version 1.15.2) for sending the player a message with his coordinates upon death. Everything worked fine until I tried to implement a command for enabling and disabling this feature.
For doing this I created a new java class, but when I tried to compile, I got this error:

```
Error:(9, 8) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor CommandExecute()
  location: class net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.CommandExecute
```

Since I am new to java I can't really think of something to fix this and therefore hope for your help!
The entire code can be seen below (JDK 1.8):

## DeathMessage.java (Main class)

```
package com.minecraft.deathmessage;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DeathMessage extends JavaPlugin {
    private CommandsClass commands = new CommandsClass();
    private final Server server = getServer();
    public Boolean enabled = false;


    public void onEnable() {
        // Initialisation Message
        server.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(
                "[DM] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "DeathMessage plugin has been enabled");

    // Event registering
    server.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventsClass(), this);

    // Command registering
    Objects.requireNonNull(getCommand(commands.cmd_header)).setExecutor(commands);

    }

    public void onDisable() {
        server.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(
                "[DM] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "DeathMessage plugin has been disabled");
    }
}
```

## EventsClass.java

```
package com.minecraft.deathmessage;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;

public class EventsClass implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event) {
        if (true) {  // this is just a placeholder for later checking if the feature is enabled or not
            Entity entity = event.getEntity();
            String entity_type = entity.getType().toString();

            if (entity_type.equals("PLAYER")) {
                Location player_location = entity.getLocation();
                int x_pos = (int) player_location.getX();
                int y_pos = (int) player_location.getY();
                int z_pos = (int) player_location.getZ();
                World world = player_location.getWorld();

                String world_string = ChatColor.GREEN + "overworld";
                if (world != null) {
                    if (world.getName().equals("world_nether")) {
                        world_string = ChatColor.RED + "nether";
                    } else if (world.getName().equals("world_the_end")) {
                        world_string = ChatColor.BLUE + "end";
                    }
                }


                entity.sendMessage("[DC] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "You died at " + ChatColor.WHITE + Integer.toString(x_pos) +
                        " " + Integer.toString(y_pos) + " " + Integer.toString(z_pos) + ChatColor.GOLD + " in the " + ChatColor.WHITE +
                        world_string + ChatColor.GOLD + "!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## CommandsClass.java

```
package com.minecraft.deathmessage;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.CommandExecute;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class CommandsClass extends CommandExecute implements Listener, CommandExecutor {
    public String cmd_header = "dm";

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There doesn't exist a constructor for the `CommadExecute` class, so it cannot be extended (as far as I know). Since there is no neccesity in using `CommandExecute` you can leave it out.